# Can you help me with the things I'm confused about FSMO role seizure?

Tags: active-directory

I need help with a specific issue. In the process of seizing FSMO (Flexible Single Master Operations) roles, I understand that data from an inaccessible server is transferred to a new server. However, if the primary server hosting the roles has crashed, how does another machine acquire this data? Does it register with an online system? Can you help me understand the logic?

I searched on the internet but couldn't find it.